# Get Position from AWT canvas coordinates in WorldWind

Tags: svg, worldwind

I want to write a transformer for converting svg basic types into worldwind shapes like polyline, polygon etc.

Since svg gives coordinates on canvas and I need to convert them to position, I am looking for a method in the api which can do this.

I see there is Vec4 for point but I am not sure how it relates to canvas coordinates.

Will it be a correct representation if for say point x=100,y=100, I do the following

```
Vec4 vec=new Vec4(x,y,0.0f);
Globe g=view.getGlobe();

Position p=g.computePositionFromPoint(vec);
```

Will this correspond position will be the position at point(x=100,y=100) on the screen. If i bring my mouse to x=100 and y=100 for the current view the position should be p.

Answer (score 2):

`Globe.computePositionFromPoint(vec)` takes Cartesian coordinates as input, not screen coordinates. To go from screen coordinates to position you want something like this:

```
Vec4 screenCoords = new Vec4(x,y);
Vec4 cartesian = view.unProject(screenCoords);
Globe g=view.getGlobe();
Position p=g.computePositionFromPoint(cartesian);
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be:

```
Point screenPoint = dragContext.getPoint();
View view = dragContext.getView();

double latitude = view.computePositionFromScreenPoint(screenPoint.getX(), screenPoint.getY()).getLatitude().degrees;
double longitude = view.computePositionFromScreenPoint(screenPoint.getX(), screenPoint.getY()).getLongitude().degrees;
Position objectPosition = new Position(LatLon.fromDegrees(latitude, longitude), 0);
```

Then you can set the position of the object to objectPosition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go from canvas to 3D, you're probably looking for `View#computeRayFromScreenPoint(double, double)`. This will give you a ray (in `Vec4` format) from the eye through the given pixel on the canvas. You'll have to intersect this ray with something to generate a meaningful 3D point, since each pixel is an infinite line in space.

---

about the `Globe#computePointFromPosition`:

`Position` - A latitude, longitude, altitude position, with the altitude being in MSL (alt above sea level)

`Vec4` - Just a directional vector (often used for Cartesian coordinates). For the Cartesian coordinate system, the z-axis comes out of the earth through 0deg/0deg lat/lon, x-axis through 0deg/90deg, and y-axis through the north pole.

As Chris mentioned, The `Globe#computePointFromPosition()` and `Globe#computePointFromPosition()` switch from a `Position` to a Cartesian `Vec4` and vice versa, using your globe as the reference frame.